# Perl escaping pound sign

Tags: perl, escaping

I have a variable and am trying to pass in the following PW:

```
my $pass    = 'trAF\#\1cMax\$\';
```

Even though I'm escaping the `#` sign, its still thinking that the string ends with an `F` and causes an error as the code thinks its missing a semi-colon.

Be interested in any thoughts.

Comment: If I wanted to escape just the pound sign, I've tried: my $pass = 'trAF\#\1cMax$'; but it still thinks of anything after the # as a comment

Comment: @user2193480 That is wrong. First off, you never have to escape `#` inside a string, because it is not a meta character, or a string that is interpolated. Second, you do not have to escape (many) things in a single quoted string in the first place, and your error comes from you escaping the last single quote `\'`.

Comment: no, it isn't well written.  it asserts that perl thinks the string ends with F but doesn't show why the user thinks that.  (in addition to the "causes an error" without showing the error)

Comment: @ysth It is quite clear what the problem is, and these kind of mistakes can result in different kinds of errors, depending on the surrounding code anyway. And also, he does say that the error is that the line is missing a semi-colon -- which is completely reasonable in the context of a missing string delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem with `#`. The only problem is that you're accidentally escaping the closing delimiter.

In single-quoted strings, you can only escape the delimiter and `\` because there's no need to escape anything else. You can even avoid escaping `\` if it's unambiguous, but that's not the case for the second `\`.

Both

```
my $pass = 'trAF#\\1cMax\\$\\';
```

and

```
my $pass = 'trAF#\1cMax\$\\';
```

assign the following string to `$pass`:

```
trAF#\1cMax\$\
```

---

If you meant to obtain the string

```
trAF#1cMax$
```

then all you need is

```
my $pass = 'trAF#1cMax$';
```

Comment: It does seem strange that escaping backslash is optional. If you have 4 backslashes in a row, what does that then mean? Two backslashes, three or four? It is ambiguous.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Need? No. Could? Yes, but I'm demonstrating how to write single-quoted literals.

Comment: @TLP, No, it's not ambiguous. `\ ` followed by another `\ ` or the delimiter always results in the second character, so `\\\\ ` will result in `\\ `. You may also write that `\\\ ` iff it's not ambiguous (not a `\ ` and not a delim).

Comment: It's a special case, is what I mean. `\n` is literal, so `\\ ` should be too, unless in front of delimiter.

Comment: @TLP, No, it's not a special case. `'...\\...'` is always `...\...`. You're suggesting the meaning of `\\ ` should change depending on where it is in the literal, which would cause readability issues and would be error-prone.

Comment: The string `\\\'` can be crafted `\\\\'` if only the last backslash should be escaped. Otherwise, you would need to do `\\\\\\'`. And it does already cause readability issues because `\ ` and `\\ ` mean the same thing. Anyway... I understand that it's a dilemma and that someone at some point made the decision that this was the least bad version.

Comment: @TLP, No, `'\x'` is not unreadable. Having two things give the same result (e.g. 3+4 and 4+3) doesn't make them unreadable. That said, I never liked that unambiguous `\ ` could be omitted.